# Textbox y button

Tags: javascript, html5, webforms

No encuentro el error.

Tengo un `Textbox`:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="un_textbox" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

luego un boton:

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server"
        Text="Pulsa"
        OnClientClick="return comprueba();" />
```

Y esto tengo en un script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function comprueba() {
        var txt = document.getElementById("un_textbox").value;
        if (txt == "hola") {
            return confirm("Confirme el postback");
        }

        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Depronto el error esta en la forma de capturar en txt asi: `document.getElementById("un_textbox").value;`?

En el `script` siempre se va por el `else`, nunca toma el `if`, como si no tuviera con que comparar el "hola"

Comment: ¿Qué error muestra? , la comparación en `Js` debería ser `if(txt==="hola")`

Comment: No me muestra error :$ Simplemente no toma el if. Me habia tragado un "=" :v Y crei que despues de eso iba a funcionar, pero no fue asi :c Pero gracias por responder.

Answer (score 1):

Creo tu problema esta cuando intentas obtener el valor del TextBox,
intenta con este código `var txt = document.getElementById('<%=un_textbox.ClientID%>').value;`

En caso de querer comprobar que te trae tu línea de código ponle un log a tu javascript y lo miras en el navegador con la opción F12 y la pestaña de console.

`console.log("Valor Text:" + txt);`

Answer (score 1):

Para identificar un control WebForms debes de utilizar la propiedad [`ClientId`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientid(v=vs.110).aspx) del control `un_textbox`:

```
  function comprueba(control) {
            var txt = document.getElementById(control).value;
            if (txt == "hola") {
                return confirm("Confirme el postback");
            }

            else {
                return false;
            }
        }
```

**Actualizacion:**

Como mencionas, tienes la funcion en el master y el control otra pagina. Lo que puedes hacer es entonces pasarle el id del control como parametro a la funcion al dar clic:

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server"
        Text="Pulsa"
        OnClientClick='return comprueba("<%= un_textbox.ClientId %>");' />
```

Comment: Para Luis y para Einer, antes que nada, gracias por atender a mi pregunta. No lo hago de esa manera pues resulta que los scripts los tengo en la pagina maestra, y los controles en la default. Entonces siempre que intento var txt = document.getElementById("<%= un_textbox.ClientId %>").value; Me resalta el id del control diciendo que no se encuentra en el contexto actual. Hay alguna forma de referenciarlo o enlazarlo desde la pagina default hasta la maestra?

Comment: @Necroyeti, mira la respuesta actualizada.

Answer (score 0):

Que bueno que especificas esa parte, bueno hasta ese punto ya tenemos algo más compresible para trabajar te recomiendo que hagas un método genérico encargado de recibir el id a lo que me refiero es que tu script reciba el controlID

```
function comprueba(controlId ) {
 jqControl = eval("'#" + controlId + "'");
    var txt = $(jqControl).val();
    if (txt == "hola") {
        return confirm("Confirme el postback");
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Cuando llames a tú método simplemente mandas el ID.
`comprueba(un_textbox.id);`